# Does std::function support perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, templates

Does `std::function` support perfect forwarding of arguments? I decided to test it:

```
struct Widget
{
    void operator()(int const&)
    {
        std::cout << "lvalue";
    }

    void operator()(int&&)
    {
        std::cout << "rvalue";
    }
};

std::function<void(int)> f{Widget()};
int x = 5;
f(x);
```

Guess which `operator()` gets called - the one taking rvalue reference. It seems that it is by design. What is the rationale behind this behavior?

Comment: Well... you kinda lied a little bit about the signature of the function object. It doesn't accept an integer by value.

Comment: `std::function<T>`'s `operator()` is constrained by `T`. If you use `void(const int&)` or `void(int&&)` instead, you'll always get the overload that you expect.

Answer (score 10):

Yes and no. Yes, the arguments are forwarded. But no, overload resolution is not done based on the arguments you provide at the point of the call - it's done based on the template arguments to `std::function`.

`std::function<void(int)>` means you have a callable that takes an `int`, which implicitly is an `int` rvalue. Calling `Widget` with an rvalue of type `int` prefers the `int&&` overload over the `int const&` overload, which is why that one is selected. It doesn't matter how you invoke the actual `function` object, once you selected that you want `void(int)` - that's the preferred overload.

The actual call operator behaves as if:

```
struct widget_function {
    void operator()(int arg) const {
//  ~~~~~           ~~~~
        w_(std::forward<int>(arg));
//                      ~~~
    }

    Widget w_;
};
```

The underlined portions come from the signature you provide to `std::function`. You can see that both `f(x)` and `f(5)` end up calling the same `operator()` from `Widget`.

---

In short, `std::function<Sig>` type erases one single overload that satisfies `Sig`. It does not type erase an entire overload set. You asked for `void(int)`, so you get `void(int)` and only `void(int)`.

Comment: You explained the mechanism, but I was also asking about the rationale. Wouldn't it be more useful if `f(x)` called lvalue overload and `f(5)` called rvalue overload?

Comment: @rubix_addict -- not in general. The point of `std::function` is that when you create an `std::function` object you define its interface. You can then populate it with **any** callable object that can be called from the `std::function` function call operator. Your `Widget` object can be used; so can a function whose prototype is `double f(double);`. And you can replace the callable object whenever you want. But you can't change the signature of that operator on the fly, so the argument types and return type cannot depend on the callable object that you've put into the `std::function` object.

Comment: I was a little surprised to see `std::forward<int>(arg)` here. Then I checked clang's implementation, it's also `forward<_ArgTypes>(__arg)`. But actually, using `forward` in this way will always select the lvalue ref version, meaning that it's just `static_cast<_ArgTypes&&>`. For me, `static_cast` looks more clear and natural.

Comment: @Barry I meant the lvalue ref version of `std::forward`. `arg` is a function parameter, so this `std::forward` is not really a forwarding, it's just `static_cast<Args&&>`.

Comment: @liliscent It's absolutely forwarding? I don't understand your comment. In this case, it's a class template parameter instead of a function template parameter, but it's doing the same thing. Something like 99% of the uses of `forward` are to forward function parameters - that's what it's for. Yeah, `forward<T>(arg)` is equivalent to `static_cast<T&&>(arg)`, but that doesn't make it not forward...

Comment: @Barry *Something like 99% of the uses of forward* ? `std::forward` is usually used for forwarding reference, but here no forwarding reference is involved. Maybe it's some cases I'm not familiar with, I'm not sure whether it's idiomatic to use a `forward` in this case.

Comment: @liliscent `_ArgTypes` could still be lvalue or rvalue references, or not references. We still want to move in the non-lvalue-reference case, so we still need `std::forward`.

Comment: @Barry `static_cast<T&&>(arg)` is *literally* equivalent to `std::forward` in this case. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward

Comment: @liliscent I still have no idea what it is you're arguing. If `static_cast<T&&>` is clearer to you, that's ... fine? But we *still need to forward* here, even if it's not in the usual form of having a function parameter that is a forwarding reference.

Comment: @Barry ...  `std::forward<T>` is always `static_cast<T&&>`, I'm dumb... Just because this case of "forwarding" looks a bit unusual... I believe you and those clang library implementors are using the idiomatic approach...

Comment: @PeteBecker I think this is a better answer. What about posting it as an answer?